# How do I get classic (not unity) desktop from run from the Live CD?

Tags: 11.04

Have been running 10.04LTS from the CD only and like it. Have no intention of ever installing Ubuntu - former Freespire user driven to Ubuntu by the lack of ability to update Firefox in Freespire.

I want a system that accesses no drives unless I tell it to and saves
absolutely nothing I have not seen and approved of.

Burned 11.04 and it seems to run, but it's useless to me if I cannot get to the older classic style - I don't want to learn how to drive again every year or so - that is one thing that drove me away from Windows.

For now, back to the 10.04 disk.

Comment: Maybe you can log out and log in with a different session or specify the session at the boot prompt somehow.

Answer (score 4):

As @queueoverflow suggest, you can logout and login in a Ubuntu Classic session.

But, first of all, it is not immediate to understand how to logout, because no such menu item appears in the system menu. This is accomplished with the command

```
gnome-session-save --logout
```

run from a terminal or from the dash after you use Alt-F2 shortcut.

Next, to login again, select *other* from the list of users, type in **ubuntu** as username and press enter.

At this point it appears the session chooser in the bottom panel. Choose *Ubuntu Classic* or *Ubuntu Classic (No effect)*, and press the **login** button, with an empty password, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. When you load Unity open a terminal and run:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Look for this line and add the nomodeset:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Save and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot.

Comment: Above answer is of course no solution - "anything that requires reboot" when running from the cd just returns the system to initial frustrating state

Comment: modify the livecd then

Comment: Burn it onto a usb with persistence.