# Way to run Ubuntu LiveCD without Unity?

Tags: 14.04, live-cd

How do we get a minimalist desktop environment from Ubuntu LiveCDs ?

From time to time I find myself in a situation where I need to try something out in a different distribution (say Ubuntu 14.04 vs 16.04, or 32 bits vs 64 bits) and running it from the corresponding LiveCD is often the quickest way to go.

By default LiveCD launches the whole Unity desktop which is great for giving Ubuntu a try, but leaves little memory to breathe if you install a lot of packages on top of it (think small laptops with 2GB ram or less).

I can't just use Lubuntu/Xubuntu LiveCD here, as I need to replicate the issue in the same distribution.

Basically I need a way to start the LiveCD, kill pretty much everything that's running and just leave Xorg and a window manager.

I'm interested in Ubuntu 14.04 primarily here, but other versions welcome.

Comment: See [How do I get classic (not unity) desktop from run from the Live CD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/42125/how-do-i-get-classic-not-unity-desktop-from-run-from-the-live-cd)

Comment: You could customize your own USB install for things like what you described.  I have 4 that I switch between.  I also have a couple of `dd` images for the occasions where I want to revert back to certain installs.

Comment: @Greenonline, It looks like this one doesn't work anymore unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

#### Crude way for Ubuntu 14.04 / 16.04

- Boot ubuntu LiveCD, click "Try Ubuntu without installing"
- Click logout (top right)
- Switch to the console: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>
- On 16.04 you need to login with user "ubuntu", empty password, then:

  ```
  $ sudo loadkeys de              # if you need a different layout
  $ sudo killall -u lightdm
  $ export DISPLAY=:0.0
  $ metacity &
  $ gnome-terminal &
  ```
- Back to graphical mode: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> (or F2 on Ubuntu 16.04)

You should now have a very minimal environment with just a terminal and window manager.

Notes:

- If you see "The system is running in low graphics mode" popup don't close it.
- If you can't access display do:

  ```
  $ sudo cp /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 ~root/.Xauthority
  $ sudo xhost +
  ```